# Is there a way to create a nested dict with a single command?

Tags: tcl

```
set my_dict [dict create a [dict create aa AA] b B]
```

Creates a dictionary which is printed as follows:

```
==> a {aa AA} b B
```

It is a nested dictionary:

```
dict get my_dict a aa 
==> AA
```

Is there a way to create a nested dict in a more elegant way, like this:

```
set my_dict [nested_dict_create {a «aa AA» b B}]
```

Obviously one can write such a command, but is there something like this in any of the lib? Trying to specify the dict naively as {a {aa AA} b BB} fails, because one can't tell the subdictionary from the simply string "aa AA". Writing a parser for such thing in the tcl itself seem to be inefficient from the glance, feature like this would be better in the core of the language or in some library written in C, and using some sort of syntax extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just create it as a literal list:

```
% set mydict {a {aa {AA}} b BB}
a {aa {AA}} b BB
% dict get $mydict a aa
AA
```

AA can be quoted or not: as a single word it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah, I see, there is no way at all for tcl to tell the string "aa AA" from the dictionary with one key "aa" and one value "AA". I know this can be _represented_ by dict or a string, but in the language they are indistinguishable. So I guess if I want some kind of "typed records", I have to include type tags explicitly in the string, like this: 
    
    {a {string {a AA}} b {dict {a AA}}}

Comment: @budden73 If you want typed records, you need to keep the type description somewhere explicitly, as Tcl's internal types largely conceal themselves. If you're doing this a lot, consider using rl_json, which is an efficient JSON library for Tcl (and where the types it supports are manifest in the syntax).

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [dict man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm) you will see that you can set a nested dictionary key by giving multiple keys in one command. However, this works only for a single nested key chain. You cannot then proceed to give additional first level keys.
In other words, you can achieve the result from your example using two separate commands:

```
dict set my_dict a aa AA
dict set my_dict b B

dict get $my_dict
> output: a {aa AA} b B
dict get $my_dict a aa
> output: AA
```